# Access array element in templates ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want get the elements of array, call appliants, he are object from class services as show my code

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= service.organ.id if service.organ %></td>
    <td><%= service.id %></td>
    <td><%= service['applicants'['type']] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In this case I need to access the key type, but I don't have success.

applicants array - `[{"type"=>"Titular da CNH.", "requirements"=>""}]`

Comment: can add example of result of `@services`

Comment: #<Service _id: 5af44a7d547bb35ed76864fc, name: "Declaração de rendimentos para bolsista Fapeal", acronym: "RENDBOLSA", popular_names: [{"name"=>"Rendimento Bolsas"}, {"name"=>"Declaração"}, {"name"=>"Bolsista Fapeal"}, {}], description: "<p>Emiss&atilde;o de declara&ccedil;&atilde;o dos&nbsp;rendimentos para bolsistas vinculados &agrave;&nbsp;Funda&ccedil;&atilde;o de Amparo &agrave; Pesquisa de Alagoas.</p>\n", free: false, applicants: [{"type"=>"Pesquisador", "requirements"=>""}, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the `type` values then you can consider joining them in a sentence, use `Array#map`

```
<%= service.applicants&.map{ |applicant| applicant['type'] }&.to_sentence %>
```

More info on `Array#map` - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-array-map-function/

`Array#to_sentence` - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence

Give it a try!

Comment: i use you sugest and get this return: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap

Comment: @Carloslima It's because in some of the rows, applicants is `nil`, I have updated my answer to handle that case, please try again

Comment: Some a question about, please, if i have a array nested, what i do to get the deep element?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: documents: [:name, cases: [:description]]. the return now are : {"name"=>"Documento oficial com foto (RG, Carteira de Trabalho, Passaporte, Carteira de Identidade Profissional ou Reservista);"}, {"name"=>"CPF;"}, {"name"=>"Comprovante de residência/Termo de Responsabilidade conforme portaria Nº 209/2013."}. And i whant get the keys name, cases: description.

Comment: Can't see cases in your above example?

Comment: Until the second layer I can, then it gives an error.

Comment: Can you show me what you are trying, I am still trying to understand the question.

Comment: Also, i have a struct who are nested. steps: [
        :title, :description,
        documents: [:name, cases: [:description]],]. You help me to get title:description, and i arrived document: name, but now i need to get cases!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing this in the view as your views should know as little as possible about the underlying models.

```
class Service
  # @return [Array]
  def applicant_types
    (applicants||[]).map {|a| a["type"] }.compact
  end
end
```

By always returning an array you can do `service.applicant_types.each do |type| ...` and be confident that it won't cause a nil error.

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted, this answer is completely legit.